# How to bundle WordPress JS and CSS files from plugins and other sources

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a WordPress website which has a lot of plugins installed, and in total there are over 100 requests on the home page.
Most of these requests are from the installed plugins.

Is there any way to bundle those resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't try that - if plugins are updated, these css and js files will be updated too, and you would have to begin again putting everything into one file. Also, unless you analyze each line of code of each plugin, you wouldn't know where the plugins actually access those files, which you would have to change too (and which also would be gone with each update).

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much what I imagined, I just hoped there was some kind of innovative solution.

Comment: well, it's in the nature of plugins that you can add and remove each one as needed, so those data need to be seperate.